# Error convert Datetime to nullable Datetime in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a list with this structure :

```
          public class Factor
    {
        public DateTime? date { set; get; }
        public string InnovoiceId { set; get; }
        public string explain { set; get; }
        public string factroyName { set; get; }
        public string tax { set; get; }
        public string transport { set; get; }
        public Int64? bedehkar { set; get; }
        public Int64? bestankar { set; get; }
        public Int64? mande { set; get; }

    }
        List<Factor> factors = new List<Factor>();
```

When i try to execute this query :

```
       foreach (Factor temp in factorSortList)
       {
           temp.date = paymentInfo.Where(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId).Select(i => i.payDate);
       }
```

Here **factorSortList** is a list of factors that is sorted. and **paymentInfo** is a list that i want to fetch some informations and put them into my current list **factorSortList** .**payDate** is a column that the datatype of that is **DateTime** .

I got this error :

```
 Error  22  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.DateTime?>' to 'System.DateTime?'
```

I

Comment: Question : what do you want in your list if source payDate is null ?

Comment: Just put "No date inserted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's not going to happen in your example, the [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could've returned more than one object. What you need to do is use [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which only returns one object:

```
temp.date = paymentInfo.First(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId).payDate);
```

Comment: what is the different between your answer and Rustam

Comment: @user3216600 It uses the `First` method instead of using `Where` and **then** `First`, meaning that it doesn't need to unnecessarily create enumerators.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
 temp.date = paymentInfo.Where(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId)
                        .Select(i => i.payDate) 
                        .First();
```

Or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to null-check:

```
temp.date = paymentInfo.Where(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId)
                        .Select(i => i.payDate) 
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I would add .FirstOrDefault(), because there aren't items for where condition, will throw a Exception

Answer (score 0):

Select returns `IEnumerable`, so you have to extract exact value; I use `First()` for it. Please try

```
   foreach (Factor temp in factorSortList)
   {
       temp.date = paymentInfo.Where(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId).Select(i => i.payDate).First();
   }
```

Comment: @user3216600 This unnecessarily creates enumerators. Please check my answer for a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @user3216600 We just answered with It'sNotALie simultaneously, his answer must be as good as mine

Comment: Hey downvoter, could you please comment, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

update your code with:

```
temp.date = paymentInfo.Where(i => i.invoiceNo == temp.InnovoiceId).Select(i => i.payDate).First();
```